# Extract numbers from a string Java

Tags: java, regex

I have string that looks like a url. For example:

```
.com/ - finds nothing
.com - finds nothing
/me - finds nothing
/me/ - finds nothing
/me/500/hello - finds nothing
/me/12/test/550        - I need find 550
/test/1500             - I need find 1500
/test/1500/            - I need find 1500
```

I need to extract always last digits, right now I do it this way

```
int index = url.lastIndexOf('/');
String found = url.substring(index + 1, url.length());
if(Pattern.matches("\\d+", found)) {
 // If found digits at the end doSometihng
}
```

However I do not like this solution, and it does not work if I have slash at the end. 
What would be nice solution to catch last digits?

Answer (score 2):

A number is last if it is not followed by any other number. In regex:

```
public static void findLastNumber() {
  String str = "/me/12/test/550/";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found : " + m.group());
  }
}
```

You can test this regular expression [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/Qe0fMrZ1Ap).

Comment: If the digits are always at the end of the string, you don't need a lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code does what you need:

```
public Integer findLastInteger(String url) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url);
  Integer out = null;
  while(scanner.hasNextInt())
    out = scanner.nextInt();
  return out;
}
```

This code returns your last integer if there is any, and returns `null` if there isn't.

Comment: This solution will also find the case `/me/500/hello --> 500`.

Comment: in this case I do not need to find it

Answer (score 0):

```
    String text = "/test/250/1900/1500/";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*)[^\\d](\\d+)(.*?)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
    }
```

The output is:

```
/test/250/1900
1500
/
```

You'll want to grab group(2).

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
.*\/(\d+)\/?
```

the first capturing group is your number.

[sample](https://regex101.com/r/fX7qU2/1)